# Reference request: $W^{2,2}$ estimates of elliptic PDE with measurable coefficients

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have some questions on solvability of the following elliptic PDE: in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for $f\in L^2$, 
$$a^{ij} u_{x^i x^j} +b^i u_{x^i} + c u = f.$$
Here $\{a^{ij}(x)\}_{i,j=1,2}$ is symmetric matrix and there is a $\kappa>0$ such that 
$$ \kappa^{-1} |\xi|^2 \geq a^{ij} \xi^i \xi^j \geq \kappa |\xi|^2$$
for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Here I used the Einstein summation convention. Also, assume that $a^{ij}, b^i, c$ are bounded and measurable. No further regularity assumption is needed (e.g. uniformly continuous, VMO condition since we work on $L^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$)

Let us denote $L = a^{ij} D_{ij} +b^i D_{i}  +c$.

According to some literature([arXiv:1404.5647](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5647.pdf)), if $a^{ij}$ are merely measurable, then there is a $W^{2,2}$-estimate for $Lu-\lambda u=f$ for large $\lambda>0$ in whole domain $\mathbb{R}^2$. They give references as follows:

- Serge Bernstein. Sur la g´en´eralisation du probl`eme de Dirichlet. Math. Ann., 69(1):82–136, 1910.
- Giorgio Talenti. Equazioni lineari ellittiche in due variabili. Matematiche (Catania), 21:339– 376, 1966.

But I fail to access these references due to language problem (French, and mathematics language problem). I cannot access the second paper in online and offline in my country.

Is their any book which give a standard proof of this question? I found some exercises from Krylov's book. But I want to find another reference.

Thanks you for in advance.

Comment: I add more sentence to claify my question. I'm interested in solvability in whole space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better behavior of elliptic PDE with measurable coefficients in two dimensions is explained by their relation with quasiconformal maps. I know two book sources that develop this relation.

1. *[Elliptic Partial Differential Equations and Quasiconformal Mappings in the Plane](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8958.html)* by Kari Astala, Tadeusz Iwaniec & Gaven Martin.
2. Chapter 12 of *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order* by David Gilbarg and Neil Trudinger.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I fail to find the desired result from that part of book. I want to find a result for whole domain, not a bounded domain. It seems like this book covers a bounded domain in that part.

Comment: GT do work on a bounded domain, AIM deal with the entire plane too, as far as I remember.

Comment: Thank you for giving another point of view.